# Angular JS Service creation Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `controller.js` file where I have created my other controllers as well, there I am creating this service using following approaches but i'm not even able to hit the service.

Following code i'm using to hit the service :-

> Snippet 1:-
>   `enrollments.myFunc();`
>   Snippet 2:-
>   `enrollments.getEnrollments()
>    .then(function() {
>     var x=response.data;
>     alert(x);
>   });`
>   Snippet 3:-
>   `enrollments.getProperty()`

Please let me know where is my mistake.

```html
helloAjaxApp.service('enrollments', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    $scope.enrollments={};
    this.myFunc = function () {
        $http({
            url : 'enrollments',
            method : "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
           $scope.enrollments = response.data;
        });
        return $scope.enrollments;
    }
}]);
```

```html
function EnrollmentService($scope, $http) {
    let _this = this;
    this.enrollments = null;
    this.getEnrollments = function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'enrollments',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response) {
            _this.enrollments = response.data;
            return _this.enrollments;
        })
    };

    this.setEnrollments = function(enrollments) {
        _this.enrollments = enrollments;
    }
}

helloAjaxApp.service('enrollments', ['$scope', '$http', EnrollmentService]);
```

```html
helloAjaxApp.factory('enrollments',  [ '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    var enrollments = null;
    enrollment();
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    $scope.enrollment=function () {
        $http({
     url : 'enrollments',
        method : "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
       enrollments = response.data;
        alert("enrollments");
    });
    };
    
    return {
       getProperty: function () {
            return enrollments;
        }
    };
    
}]);
```

Comment: **Describe the problem.** Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: I`m not getting any error,service not even called,i just want to know how can i call a service like this  from different controllers ,that`s all.

Comment: `$scope` is not injectable in services. You should be getting an error for that.

Comment: Plz, tell me what is the correct way to create a service ,which internally makes an ajax call  to fetch data from server and return it, and how to call this service also. I`m new to AngularJS

Comment: You need to replace your `$scope` in the service with `var`. `$scope` is not allowed in your service.